# Clifford Multiplication and Spinor Bundles

Tags: fiber-bundles, clifford-algebras, spin-geometry

I am trying to follow the discussion of Clifford multiplication on page 384 of *The Wild World of 4-Manifolds*, by Alexandru Scorpan ([link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821837494), although I hope this will be totally self-contained), and I'm having some trouble understanding how he gets the defining property of the multiplication.

The setup, which I believe I understand, is that a spin structure on a 4-manifold splits because of the isomorphism
$$Spin(4)= SU(2)\times SU(2)$$
so we have two $SU(2)$ spinor bundles, $\mathcal{S}^+$ and $\mathcal{S}^-$, with "complex plane fibers" (I think that means $\mathbb{C}^2$-fibers).

Now the part I don't get, is he says there is a "Clifford multiplication"
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
T_M\times \mathcal{S}^+\to \mathcal{S}^-\qquad \phi\to v*\phi,
\end{equation}
which, when you combine it with its adjoint $\mathcal{S}^-\to \mathcal{S}^+$, it's clear you must always have
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
v*(v*\phi)=-|v|^2\phi.
\end{equation}

So I certainly recognize the defining property of Clifford algebras in (2), but I don't understand how you can get it in this context. Specifically:

1. Does this Clifford multiplication promote the spinors in $\mathcal{S}$ to some kind of module?
2. (Related) If $\phi\in\mathcal{S}^+$, how am I to understand $v*\phi\in\mathcal{S}^-$? Is this a particular aspect of the grading of the Clifford algebra that I am missing?
3. How exactly is the adjoint map defined? To me, the adjoint of a map $f:X\to Y$ is a map $f^\dagger:Y^*\to X^*$, $f^\dagger(\lambda)\to \lambda\circ f$. So if my multiplication is $f(v,\phi)=v*\phi$, the adjoint would seemingly be $f_v^\dagger(\lambda)=\lambda\circ(v*\phi)$ for $\lambda\in \mathcal{S}^{-*}$. So it would appear he is implying something like $\lambda=-<v,\cdot>$ for a particular tangent vector $v$. But that seems like quite an arbitrary choice here - I must not be understanding what is meant here by "adjoint".

Comment: About 1., as expected by their interchangeable roles, there is a similar Clifford multiplication swapping "+" and "-". Both multiplications make the direct sum $\mathcal{S}^+ \oplus \mathcal{S}^-$ a Cliff$_4$-module.